# Permanent Material Overrides to Linked Files When Reloading

Tags: linked-data

I am building a neighborhood model from my home town all based on old photos. There will probably be around 100 highly detailed buildings and street furniture.

Match photo on Sketchup is essential to my modeling, and would like to continue using it. To combine all the buildings, I was going to export the Sketchup files and import them into Blender, then link those files into a master Blender file. I anticipate actively updating each file as I find more information, so having a live link from the individual models to the master file is important.

What I am worried about is losing all my material settings. If I link a building, set all the materials in Blender, find I made a mistake, correct it on Sketchup, then go through the process of reloading it into Blender, it looks like I will lose a considerable amount of time redoing all the materials.

What would be a better workflow here? I am open to using other programs to combine all the files. The important thing is to keep all the links/references live.

Comment: What is the export/import file format?  obj?  fbx?   Can you export or import a subset of only the objects you needed to change?

Comment: I was going to do DAE.

Regardless of what I do to the individual building, as soon as I would reload the linked file, I would lose my overrides.